# Getting undefined reference to OpenCV elements even when linking libraries. Using CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  Mat image = imread ("tree.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  imshow ("Grayscale Image", image);
  waitKey (0);
  return 0;
}
```

But I get undefined references to all the OpenCV elements. From reading on the site it seems this happens because of problems with linking the OpenCV libraries.

Is there a problem with my CMake file?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Programming)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS C:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(project ${OpenCV_LIBS})

MESSAGE("OpenCV_LIBS: " ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

The OpenCV libraries seem to be found:

```
OpenCV_LIBS: opencv_calib3dopencv_coreopencv_dnnopencv_features2dopencv_flannopencv_gapiopencv_highguiopencv_imgcodecsopencv_imgprocopencv_mlopencv_objdetectopencv_photoopencv_stitchingopencv_videoopencv_videoioopencv_world
```

So I'm not sure the problem is.

EDIT: This is the complete error message:

```
====================[ Build | project | Debug ]=================================
C:\Users\adibo\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion2020.3\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug --target project -- -j 3
/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2020.3/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -S/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming -B/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 project
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug'
/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2020.3/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -S/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming -B/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2020.3/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles 2
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CMakeFiles/project.dir/all
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug'
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/project.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug'
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug && /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2020.3/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/project.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug'
/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/project.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++.exe   -isystem /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/include  -g   -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o -c /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable project.exe
/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2020.3/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/project.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++.exe -g  -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o  -o project.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libproject.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0   -LC:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib  /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib /cygdrive/c/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world454d.lib 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o:/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make:123: project.exe] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:99: CMakeFiles/project.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:106: CMakeFiles/project.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: project] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/adibo/Programming/CLionProjects/Programming/cmake-build-debug'
```

Comment: Can you add the complete error message?

Comment: Yes, I added it to the post

Comment: set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)  : add this to your cmake file and add the complete output.

Comment: Ok, I added the complete output

Comment: Ok, so apparently all libraries redirect to opencv world, wich is the master module. Ar you able to check with the nm command if all the required symbols are present in this library ? (e.g., "nm opencv_world454d.lib | grep imread" in the cygwin command line)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your openCV libraries are installed in a non standard path, and the names in OpenCV_LIBS do not give you an absolute path. You need to indicate to the linker where to find the libraries.

To do that, you can use the target_link_directories() cmake command. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_directories.html

I guess the path you want to pass it is "C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib".

Comment: I added this line after `add_executable(project main.cpp)`: `target_link_directories(project PUBLIC C:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib)`, but it gives the same error message